# Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (14:13)

Tags: reactjs, jsx, babeljs

i've been using react.js and this is the first time this happened , am developing the front-end of an app set up with parcel-bundler and i got this problem when i was writing simple jsx code .

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (15:13):
  13 |     }
  14 | 
> 15 |     getCars = () => {
     |            ^
  16 |         console.log('hi')
  17 |     }
```

i tried installing @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties and setting up a .babelrc file as i seen when i googled the error but its the same problem

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
            {
                "loose": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue.

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.0.0"
...
  }
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is it the solution?

Comment: Doesn't really make sense to add a `.babelrc` just for parcel to work. This is a parcel issue and should be handled by parcel, as they say it's zero-config, so by default this should work. I also tried adding a .babelrc to my project but I kept getting more and more errors (as I use React, TypeScript and other libraries).